# How to create 3D signed distance function?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, 3d

I am trying to segment a 3D shape using levelset. I want to track shape movement in consecutive frames.

Now I want to create a `signed distance function` matrix for initialization of levelset algorithm using previous frame surface calculated as 3D points.

First, I have to create a logical 3D matrix in which all points inside previous frame surface points are '1' and '0' otherwise. Then I have to calculate `3D signed distance function` matrix from it.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.